# JS проверка input value

Tags: javascript

Есть задача, нужно проверить содержимое поля input.
Если в поле input слово "google" и нажать на button - будет alert - "Okay!".
Если что-либо другое и нажать на button - будет alert с введенными данными в input.
Почему-то пропускает проверку if и идет к else, не понимаю...Помогите, если не трудно, спасибо!

найти!

```
<script>

    let button = document.getElementById('button');
    let search = document.getElementById('search');

    if (search.value == "google") {
        button.addEventListener ('click', () => alert ("Okay!"));;
    } else {
        button.addEventListener ('click', () => alert (search.value));;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: HTML : <input id="search" class="input" type="text" name="" placeholder="Найти">
    <button id="button" class="button">найти!</button>

Comment: вам нужно условие делать в обработчике нажатия на кнопку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас неверная логика. Вы сравниваете значение из инпута и в зависимости от условия навешиваете слушателя, который при клике на кнопку выдаёт значение.

Нужно сделать так: вначале вешаете слушателя на кнопку и вот только при клике на неё делаете проверку условия (в колэк функции слушателя)

```js
let button = document.getElementById('button');
let search = document.getElementById('search');

button.addEventListener ('click', () => {
    if (search.value == "google") {
        alert("Okay!");
    } else {
       alert(search.value);
    }    
});
```

```html
<input id="search">
<button id="button">click</button>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за детальное разьяснение!!! Работает! Только учу js, пока не всё получается( еще раз спасибо :)))))

Comment: @YuliyaKisilyova если ответ решил вашу проблему, отметьте его как принятый пожалуйста. Галочкой.

Answer (score 2):

Делай проверку внутри листенера

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (search.value === 'google') {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо :) теперь поняла, работает :)